# Getting new access token from LI API

Tags: php, mysql, linkedin-api, token, access-token

I am getting Access token from LI API in PHP , My code does that but the token expires after some time, so I need to refresh it , How I can do that. this is my code

```
global $config;
        $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                        'client_id' => $config['linkedin_key'],
                        'client_secret' => $config['linkedin_secret'],
                        'code' => $_GET['code'],
                        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUrl
                  );

                 // var_dump($params);
        $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);
        $context = stream_context_create(
                        array('http' => 
                            array('method' => 'POST',
                            )
                        )
                    );
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $token = json_decode($response);
        return $token->access_token;
```

Comment: a refresh token is the oauth approach, read the doocs, ever implementation of oauth is different

Comment: @Dagon I read that I dont know what I am missing

Comment: instructions are here: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens